# Adding a cookie in gatling request

Tags: scala, cookies, gatling

I am trying to send an explicit cookie value along with my request. I have added the below line at the top of my request. But this does not work. I do not see the cookie is being sent as part of this request from the server logs.

```
exec(addCookie(Cookie("mycookiename", "1")
            .withDomain("www.image.iot.dev")
            .withPath("/")
            .withSecure(true)))
```

Appreciate if someone can help on this.

Comment: It should work. Your mistake is probably elsewhere. Maybe your addCookie and request are not properly attached (missing dot).

Comment: In most of cases cookie domain should start with a dot, so try `.image.iot.dev`